# UIPanGestureRecognizer doesn't work initially

Tags: uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer, tvos

I have a UICollectionView cell and I want to add some custom parallax animation when focused. Basically, I'm adding the UIPanGestureRecognizer to the cell's `contentView` on focus and removing it on unfocus. This works, HOWEVER, not initially.

When I focus on a cell the UIPanGestureRecognizer listener function - `viewPanned:` - doesn't get called. If I take my finger off the remote, and then touch it again, only then does `viewPanned:` get called.

Even more strange, if I focus on a different cell, but then come back to that cell that worked, it will then work initially without me having to take my finger off the remote.

Here's my UIPanGestureRecognizer:

```
    private lazy var panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer = {
        let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self,
            action: Selector("viewPanned:")
        )
        pan.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        return pan
    }()
```

The focus-related code:

```
    // MARK: Focus
    override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
        super.didUpdateFocusInContext(context, withAnimationCoordinator: coordinator)

        coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({ () -> Void in
            if self.focused {
                self.focusItem()
            } else {
                self.unfocusItem()
            }
            }) { () -> Void in
        }
    }


    func focusItem() {
        // -- (need slight delay otherwise jumps because of other focus animation
        let dispatchTime: dispatch_time_t = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            //                print(" ---- adding pan")
            self.contentView.addGestureRecognizer(self.panGesture)
        })

    }

    func unfocusItem() {
        contentView.removeGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    }
```

And the panning code:

```
  // MARK: Focus - Panning (Custom focus animation for rounded cells)
    private var initialPanPosition: CGPoint?
    func viewPanned(pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        switch pan.state {
        case .Began:

            print(" ---- PAN -- BEGAN")

            initialPanPosition = pan.locationInView(contentView)
        case .Changed:

//            print(" ---- PAN -- CHANGED")

            if let initialPanPosition = initialPanPosition {
                let currentPosition = pan.locationInView(contentView)
                let diff = CGPoint(
                    x: currentPosition.x - initialPanPosition.x,
                    y: currentPosition.y - initialPanPosition.y
                )

                // -- parallax imageView
                let parallaxCoefficientX = 1 / self.contentView.frame.width * 10
                let parallaxCoefficientY = 1 / self.contentView.frame.height * 10
                if (isRounded) {
                    self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(
                        diff.x * parallaxCoefficientX,
                        diff.y * parallaxCoefficientY
                    )
                }

                // -- parallax transformView
                let parallaxCoefficientTransFormViewX = 1 / self.contentView.frame.width * 2
                let parallaxCoefficientTransFormViewY = 1 / self.contentView.frame.height * 2
                var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
                if (!isRounded) {   // -- not rounded cells already scale up the entire contentView
                    transform = CATransform3DScale(transform, Constants.FocusedTransformViewScaleTransform, Constants.FocusedTransformViewScaleTransform, 1.0)
                }
                transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform,
                    diff.x * parallaxCoefficientTransFormViewX,
                    diff.y * parallaxCoefficientTransFormViewY,
                    0)
                self.transformView.layer.transform = transform


        }
        default:
            // .Canceled, .Failed, etc.. return the view to it's default state.

//            print(" ---- PAN -- DEFAULT")

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3,
                delay: 0,
                usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8,
                initialSpringVelocity: 0,
                options: .BeginFromCurrentState,
                animations: { () -> Void in

                    if (self.isRounded) {
                        self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(1.0,1.0)
                    }
                },
                completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

---

EDIT

Instead of adding/removing the gesture recognizer on focus/unfocus, I tried just adding it on initialization and implementing this:

```
  override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

    if (gestureRecognizer == panGesture) {
        if (focused) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

However, for some reason an unfocused cell will still receive the gesture. Adding/removing it is the only way I can prevent this.

---

EDIT #2

I also just tried implementing the following, thinking the focus engine gesture recognizers are interfering, but it didn't fix the issue:

```
    func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,
shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried just adding the gesture detector when the cell is created and using UIGestureRecognizerDelegate's gestureRecognizerShouldBegin to control whether or not it should fire (based on if you have focus)?

Comment: I tried a variation of that using a flag (didn't think to use the existing focused flag) but an unfocused cell continued to receive the gesture. I just tried using the focused flag and same thing (see edit)

Comment: Did you set the delegate property on each gesture recognizer to the object that implements that method?

Comment: @i_am_jorf yeah - it hits the delegate methods